# Changing data by lookuptable

Tags: java, opencv, lookup-tables, android

In an Android app I'm developing (using OpenCV4Android) I have a matrix (`Mat` object) that contains integer values, and another row-matrix that is the lookup table. I need to create a new matrix in the size of the first one, where each value is replaced with the corresponding lookup-table value (i.e `newMat(x,y) = lookupTable(oldMat(x,y))`).

For starters, I know there's a `Core.LUT()` function, but it won't help here because I don't necessarily work with `CvType.CV_8U` typed `Mat`s, and the lookup table may be larger than 256 values. I will mostly work with single channel floats (`CvType.CV_32FC1`).

I came up with this solution:

```
// init matrices
Mat oldMat = initOldMat(); // contains values from 0 to k-1
Mat newMat = new Mat(oldMat.size(), oldMat.type());
Mat LUT = initLUT(); // a row matrix with k columns

// copying data from matrices to arrays
float[] oldMatArr = new float[(int)oldMat.total()];
oldMat.put(0,0,oldMarArr);
float[] lutArr= new float[(int)LUT.total()];
oldMat.put(0,0,lutArr);

// initialize array for the new matrix
float[] newMatArr = new float[oldMatArr.length];

// applying the LUT - see function below
applyLUTonData(oldMatArr, lutArr, newMatArr);

// copy the data to the new matrix
newMat.put(0, 0, newMatArr);



private void applyLUTonData(float[] inputData, float[] lut, float[] outputData) {

        if (inputData.length != outputData.length) {
            Log.e(TAG, "applyLUTonData: inputData.length != outputData.length", new IllegalArgumentException("inputData.length != outputData.length"));
        }
        if (Floats.min(inputData) < 0 || Floats.max(inputData) > lut.length) {
            Log.e(TAG, "applyLUTonData: Invalid values in inputData", new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid values in inputData"));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
            if (inputData[i] != Math.round(inputData[i])) { // not an int
                Log.e(TAG, "applyLUTonData: inputData contains non-integers", new IllegalArgumentException("inputData contains non-integers"));
            }
            outputData[i] = lut[(int) inputData[i]];
        }
    }
```

Note: I know that it is a bit weird that the `inputData` contains floats. Of course I can convert it for some integer type matrix/array, but I still won't be able to use `Core.LUT` because my `LUT` may contain non-integer values.

It is working, which is great **but** it is very inefficient - this function is called in a nested for loop, up to `3*k` times (`k` is the LUT size), and it takes a lot of time. So, I'm looking for an efficient way to achieve the same functionality. It may use either Java or OpenCV solutions (including libraries like Guave etc.) - whichever works.

Comment: you could have a look at the opencv source code whether you can adapt the 8UC1 code for you 32F version.

Comment: @Micka I tried to look at it, but it's written in C++, and it's not easy (if it is possible at all) to adapt it into Java

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution - instead of converting the `Mat` objects into arrays, I keep them as `Mat`s, and pass them to the function. The idea is to "slice" it to the amount of values in the LUT, dealing with each value at a time. For example - for a LUT containing 32 different values, I'll go over the input data (which contains integers from 0 to 31), first replace all the 0's, then 1's, and so on...

Here's my code:

```
private static void applyLUTonData(Mat inputData, float[] LUT, Mat outputData, int nBins) {
        if (inputData.rows() != outputData.rows() || inputData.cols() != outputData.cols()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "applyLUTonData: inputData.size() != outputData.size()", new IllegalArgumentException("inputData.size() != outputData.size()"));
            return;
        }

        if (LUT.length != nBins) {
            Log.e(TAG, "applyLUTonData: Invalid length for LUT - " + nBins, new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid length for LUT - " + nBins));
            return;
        }

        Core.MinMaxLocResult res = Core.minMaxLoc(inputData);
        if (res.minVal < 0 || res.maxVal >= nBins) {
            Log.e(TAG, "applyLUTonData: Invalid inputData values", new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid inputData values"));
            return;
        }
        // here's the magic
        Mat cmpMat = new Mat();

        for (int i = 0; i < nBins; i++) {
            Core.compare(inputData, new Scalar(i), cmpMat, Core.CMP_EQ);
            outputData.setTo(new Scalar(LUT[i]), cmpMat);
        }
        cmpMat.release();
    }
```

Complexity speaking, for n-pixels image, my older version took O(n). This version with LUT of size k takes O(k), which is a great improvement for the usual case where k << n.